# Objective-c How To Segue from within a UITableView Sub Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Yesterday I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655124/objective-c-uitableview-separate-class-cellforrowatindexpath-does-not-get-called) so all of the code can be found there for the structure of my problem.

**The Problem... This Time**

I have come from other languages to OBJ-C and some of the OOP structures are making me cringe a little bit (I don't like packing every possible function into a single `UIViewController` as some seem to do). I was originally going to make a full page `UITableViewController` with an embedded `NavigationController` however the use cases of this project would not allow me to use the default navbar. So I had to put in my own navbar and use a regular `UITableView` (resized to be pretty much full screen) instead of the simpler option, the `UITableViewController`... (I am aware this all could be solved by using it, but I cannot)

Instead I have a regular `UIViewController` with a property containing my own custom `TasksTableView.h` subclass. The subclass extends `UITableView` as seen in the link I posted above.

*The actual problem* is that I cannot seem to Segue or change views from inside of this `UITableView` because every function which does so, seems to need to come from the `UIViewController` class.

**I Have Tried**

Calling a manual segue in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of my `UITableView` subclass.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profile" sender:sender];
```

Which produces an obvious error telling me that `performSegueWithIdentifier` does not exist on this class, which it doesn't so thats fine. Obviously it belongs to the `UIViewController` class that instantiated my `UITableView` sub class...

I have tried importing the view controller that actually renders and holds the property of my table view subclass itself and trying to push the view to the stack.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *target = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SingleTaskViewController"];

    AllTasksViewController *allTasksView = [[AllTasksViewController alloc] init];

    if(target) {
        [target setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
        [allTasksView presentViewController:target animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

This gives me the error `Warning: Attempt to present <SingleTaskViewController: 0x7fa15d5359f0> on <AllTasksViewController: 0x7fa15d5363c0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`
 ... Even though it must be in the heirarchy because it is the view that contains and instantiated this `UITableView`.

I have also tried manually invoking the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` from the `UIViewController` that holds the `UITableView` sub class but again it was the same kinda thing. It invoked, however obviously since I had to pass in the index, it is me picking it instead of the table telling me what was actually selected.

**What I Want**

I would really like to keep the `UITableView` sub class seperate from the `UIViewController` and not bring the delegate methods and protocols to the view controller. I would prefer to keep the logic separated. All I need is a way to segue or transition to the Single Task View in question and send some data with it about what was pressed.

Comment: you should call performSegueWithIdentifier only if you set up a segue in the IB!, and the self in this call refers to the UIViewController, but not any of its subviews!

Comment: I tried that, it says that the method `performSegueWithIdentifier` does not exist!

Comment: you can only call it on class that are subclass of UIViewController

Comment: The answer you got to your previous question was a little... hmmm... odd. You do *not* need to subclass `UITableView` to separate data and actions - you can simply create a `UITableViewDelegate` class and a `UITableViewDataSource` class, and assign those to your table view. In either case, you want to use a Delegate Protocol pattern to "call back" to your View Controller class to perform the segue.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri lol then why did you suggest it?

Comment: wow @DonMag thanks that is WAY cleaner to have the DataSource and delegate's both subclassed to their own space. Much much cleaner. I will begin researching the callback approach, any chance you can submit an answer and provide a heuristic? Is it anything like a regular closure or JS callback type of thing using blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are good tutorials out there, but the basic idea is...

- Main "ViewController" class - contains a Table View, and a "manual" Segue to a "Profile" View controller
- Separate Datasource and Delegate classes for the table view
- Custom Protocol / Delegate to send the "didSelectRow" action

When the main vc loads, it creates instances of the Datasource and Delegate classes, and assigns them to the table view.

It also "conforms to" a custom Protocol in the Delegate class. This allows the Delegate class to "call back" to the main vc when a row is tapped.

I put together a very simple example demonstrating this approach that can be seen here: https://github.com/DonMag/OCTableViewExample